# The telegram telethon group online count

Tags: telethon

[online status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L1gL.jpg)I add many account to a public group.When the number is lower than 50，the group online count is right.But when the number is higher than 50, the online count miss or the number is lower than the correct number so far.In fact the online count is 200，the app show the group online count is 2.Please help.It is emergency